# How do I use a combobox and textbox on a userform in VBA to search and find data on the active Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, textbox

I've been trying to look for answers for the past two days and I still don't understand how to code this. I am learning VBA as I go for a project but I am more familiar with vb.net coding. So for this project, I have to add/update/delete data. In the update and delete button clicks, I have to search for the data using the conditions that the information searched is under the column chosen from the combobox and it has data from what is keyed in the textbox.

I do not know how to code both conditions together. The farthest I have gotten based on research is coding a Find method that searches and selects through the active sheet cells only by what is keyed in the textbox. How would I code the combobox as one of the conditions linked with what is in the textbox in order to  search the spreadsheet successfully?

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Dim strFindWhat As String
    strFindWhat = TextBox1.Text

    On Error GoTo ErrorMessage

    Cells.Find(What:=strFindWhat, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _False).Select
    Exit Sub
    ErrorMessage:
        MsgBox ("The data you are searching for does not exist")

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:D1").Value)
End Sub
```

Spreadsheet:

[image: SpreadSheet]

Delete button click:

[image: Delete Button Click]

Textbox used for Search:

[image: Textbox used for Search]

Need to implement the combobox condition to search text only within the column specified:

[image: Need to implement the combobox condition to search text only within the column specified]

Comment: *This is my code so far* far away...

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally created my post before putting my code. I just added it.

Comment: It's not really clear without the actual workbook...

Comment: Okay, let me add some screenshots.

Comment: I added my screenshots...does it make more sense what I am trying to do?

Comment: *search text only within the column specified* - so, instead of `[ActiveSheet.]Cells.Find`, do `ActiveSheet.Range("your column").Find`

Comment: I think I've tried something similar and it just takes me to the error message. The combobox option still doesn't work when I tried to change that code.

Comment: **TIP:** When deleted rows (if that is one of your goals) be sure to make your buttons `ActiveX` controls and NOT `Form` controls. If you delete a row when a `Form` control is, you may delete a part of (or even the entire) control. `ActiveX` controls are not deleted. Or just be careful to only delete the range you want and not the entire row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So her is a new Solution. You have to declare 3 Public Variables in the UserForm1 Modul. So you can give them Values while the USerForm is open and Find the Naxt Values when you click multiple Times on the Search Button.

```
'Public Variables 
    Public bolFirstSearch As Boolean
    Public rng As Excel.Range
    Public cellFound  As Excel.Range

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    bolFirstSearch = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim strFindWhat As String
Dim intRowCB As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrorMessage
If UserForm1.bolFirstSearch = False Then

    strFindWhat = TextBox1.Text
    intRowCB = Cells.Find(What:=ComboBox1.value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
    Set rng = Columns(intRowCB)
    rng.Select
        Set cellFound = rng.Find(What:=strFindWhat, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        cellFound.Select
Else

    Set cellFound = rng.FindNext(cellFound)
    cellFound.Select
End If
UserForm1.bolFirstSearch = True
Exit Sub
ErrorMessage:

 MsgBox ("The data you are searching for does not exist")
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:D1").Value)
    bolFirstSearch = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    bolFirstSearch = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This code almost worked, but when I tried to continue search-click it didn't budge. It only coded to find the first value in the column with the keyed text and wouldn't continue searching through the column. So I'm not sure how to make it a continuous search if I keep clicking the search click.

Comment: @Destiny ok. I updated my Answer. Hope this will Help

Comment: This almost worked again, but for some reason if I enter data that can be found within the column, it finds it, and then when I enter data that isn't within the column, instead of going to error message, it highlights the previous results found. I'm not sure if I need to fix where I place the error message or not?

Comment: @Destiny you need to add in the ´Private Sub TextBox1_Change()´ Event
    **bolFirstSearch = False**´

Comment: Do you know how I would code the delete button based off the search? Since I want the search button to find the information. I would like that specific cell data to be deleted but since the command buttons are private  subs, how would I transfer that variable as what I want to delete with the delete button?

Comment: @Destiny just use the cellFound Variable. that's a public variable

Answer (score 0):

```
 Public Sub FindValueInColumn(bolDelete As Boolean, strColumnText As String, _
                              strSearchValue As String, strSheetName)

    Dim intColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim rngSearchRange As Range

    On Error Goto ErrHandler

    'Find Column Index
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
        Set rngSearchRange = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Find(What:=strColumnText, lookat:=xlWhole)
    End With

    If Not rngSearchRange Is Nothing Then
        intColumnIndex = rngSearchRange.Column
    End If

    If intColumnIndex > 0 then
        'Find value in specified column
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
            Set rngSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, intColumnIndex),.Cells(Rows.Count, intColumnIndex).End(xlUp)).Find(What:=strSearchValue, lookat:=xlPart)
        End With

        If rngSearchRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Value not found."
        Else
        If bolDelete Then
            rngSearchRange.ClearContents
        Else
            rngSearchRange.Select
        End
    Else
        MsgBox "Column not Found"
    End If
Exit sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong there."
    On Error Goto 0
End Sub
```

This is basically a two job action: Find your target column, then find your search value within that column. Simply call the sub from your buttons. From the delete button pass `bolDelete` as `true`, from the search button as `false`.

As a general hint: Error handlers are good practise but raising errors to achieve functionality is not(at least where it can be avoided with proper tests). Also selections are never necessary in VBA and create unnecessary overhead.

This doesn't account for everything as I don't know the rest of your code. I recommend using this as a reference and implement it rather than copypaste it.